# CORS related errors when getting Channel API client script

Tags: google-app-engine, go, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm currently experimenting with a Google App Engine/Go + Polymer.dart website at http://xclamm.appspot.com/.

The problem is that I get the following error when I access http://xclamm.appspot.com/ with Dartium (31.0.1612.0 Developer Build 219647).

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xclamm.appspot.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I did some research and found that the problem is related with how I refer to `/_ah/channel/jsapi`, but I can't find how to fix it. I tried the following ways to refer to channel.js, but I still get the same error.

```
<!-- Following doesn't work -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
<!-- Following doesn't work either -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js"></script>
```

If I run the website on dev_appserver.py, it seems to be working OK. Am I missing something?

The source code is available at https://github.com/rillomas/xclamm-gae, and I'm using Google App Engine SDK 1.8.4 for Go (x64 Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the `<script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>` tag from `main-stage.html` (html for an internal web component) to `index.html` (root html for the website), and the CORS error went away.

The `<script>` tag was originally placed inside a `<polymer-element>` tag, and was (probably) translated to an XMLHttpRequest by Polymer.dart, causing the error.